# SQL Find elements that match two conditions, each from different tables

Tags: sql

Table: University

| university | state |
| --- | --- |
| UCLA | CA |
| CUNY | NY |
| UCB | CA |
| USC | CA |
| UM | MI |
| NYU | NY |

Table: UniColor

| university | color |
| --- | --- |
| UCLA | RED |
| UNY | BLUE |
| UCB | RED |
| USC | ORANGE |
| UM | CYAN |
| NYU | BLUE |

Desired Result:

| university1 | university2 | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UCB | UCLA | CA |
| CUNY | NYU | CA |

I'm trying to get pairings of universities that are located in the same place and have same symbol color? My initial approach is

```
SELECT t0.name, t1.name, co.color
FROM University AS t0,
     University AS t1,
     UniColor AS co
WHERE t0.university = co.university
  AND t0.state = t1.state
GROUP BY co.color
HAVING COUNT(c.color) > 1
```

but it's clearly not working. Could anyone please help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: Aggregate(such as count) need group by and you don't need to join university table twice

Comment: Are you really taught implicit, comma separated joins in 2022?!? Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: You can use COUNT, HAVING clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with uni_data as (
SELECT u.university, u.state, c.color
FROM university u
INNER JOIN UniColor c on u.university = c.university
)
SELECT u1.university, u2.university, u1.state
FROM uni_data u1
INNER JOIN uni_data u2 ON
  u1.state = u2.state AND
  u1.color = u2.color AND
  u1.university < u2.university -- ensures only a,b not b,a as well
```